# Change return value of super class' static constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-class

I want to extend a class by only adding a new (non static) function, without changing the constructor. My super class can only be constructed from a static function. Now, when I construct my sub class with that static function, I receive an object that is an instance of the super class although I want the sub class. What can I do to achieve what I am looking for without changing the super class?

Here is a minimal example:

```js
class MySuperClass {
    static staticConstructor() {
        return new MySuperClass()
    }
}

class MySubClass extends MySuperClass {
    addedFunction() {}
}

const mySuperClass = MySuperClass.staticConstructor()
console.log(mySuperClass instanceof MySuperClass) // true

const mySubClass = MySubClass.staticConstructor()
console.log(mySubClass instanceof MySubClass) // false, I want this to be true
console.log(mySubClass instanceof MySuperClass) // true

// calling mySubClass.addedFunction results in an error due to wrong instance
```

PS: I could not find a solution here but I am quite sure there should be one. Every search resulted in some DOM manipulation that I am obviously not looking for.

Comment: The `staticConstructor` should use `return new this()`

Comment: Damn I feel dumb. Thank you, that helped! Do you know how to properly type the return value of staticConstructor in Typescript? I guess this will only be correct for my subclass using Generics or any?

Comment: Yes, I suspect you need generics for that. There are a few TypeScript issues related to this, e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that your static constructor will always return an instance of the SuperClass whatever subclasses you may create. For your second `console.log` to return true, you need to replace the static constructor code by `return new this()`

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I would properly type the return value of the `staticConstructor` in Typescript? Is this only achievable by using Generics?

Comment: What do you mean by Generics  ? If I'm not mistaken is it related the the `any` keyword in TS ?

Comment: I ment this `<T extends MySuperClass` to properly type the return value of my constructor: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=40&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBlArgBwKYCcDC4rQG8BYAKGnOggBcwqBLYSm+4bAewDtrNlgq3MAHgAq0dAA8q6DgBMYCFBhx4IAPgAUASgBc0UcTIUjmdFWSYO0DugDu0KgAs6ELdEh7SRgL6kfJUqCQ8kjIAEa4QWKS0nJwIUoR+AZGYDIy6DIAYsgcfHScrslGFCZmFtAAjJ4Ufn4BnNTQALbxWIkwALxxim0qAHTUtAzsXFQ8fAJa9VxsIOh9IGwA5uotPcqRdKNguehsAGbdaL1BmtAA9Of2POik041rYe3QXQpP-YMsI9y8-EJv4RUGk091m80WK0egM2212ByO0KgZ0u0H2YBAEFuJGADTBC2WqxCiJgW0GcMObwSKmRVzGyCxOJmc3xkKJ7T6qXSWRyeQKmk0QA

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not skilled enough in TypeScript to answer your question. You may refer to @Bergi for that, the link he provided to you or even create a new question for that matter.